# Android Studio not uninstalling

Tags: android-studio

I have a Win 10 Pro v. 1803 system fully updated. Neither the Uninstall function in Settings > Apps nor the uninstall.exe in Program Files > Android > Android Studio work. I get 'Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device' and then nothing more happens. Once I got the pulsing circle that indicates the system works on something for 1 hour but still nothing really happened.

Comment: Use perfect uninstaller.

Comment: The trial version doesn't remove apps, and the company doesn't exist any more. I get 'This domain name has expired' under 'http://www.perfectuninstaller.com/register/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to fully uninstall the android studio or any other program that is not getting done by using windows

use [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/uninstall_view.html)